# expresssion field=xxx after group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

mysql server version: mysql 5.6
client: datagrip

my expected sql is

`select * from user GROUP BY level;`

but I wrongly executed

`select * from user GROUP BY level=1;`

I thought mysql will throw an error, but it don't.
and mysql return me a rows.

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It will return the last row of the table and the matched row where level = 1.**

For Example:

```
CategoryID    CategoryName      Description
1             Beverages         Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales
2             Condiments        Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings
3             Confections       Desserts, candies, and sweet breads
4             Dairy Products    Cheeses
5             Grains/Cereals    Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal
6             Meat/Poultry      Prepared meats
7             Produce           Dried fruit and bean curd
8             Seafood           Seaweed and fish
```

The below query :

```
SELECT CategoryID,CategoryName,Description FROM Categories GROUP BY CategoryID = 3
```

will result into:

```
CategoryID  CategoryName    Description
8            Seafood        Seaweed and fish
3            Confections    Desserts, candies, and sweet breads
```

Comment: why? any specification about group by?